# Javascript whack-a-mole game finishing messages stack

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a whack-a-mole game in Javascript.  There are 9 images written into the html.  When the game starts, one will randomly become a mole every second.  If the user clicks such an image, it adds to their score.  Meanwhile, a timer ticks away, so eventually when the game stops, the user can see their score/time ratio in an alert message.  The user can start the game either by clicking a button that gives him infinite time until he clicks the stop button, or by clicking the "one minute" or "two minutes" buttons, which will keep the game going for that respective amount of time and then stop, or the user can click stop at any time during the game.  Regardless, it will again present the user with a score/time ratio.

The problem is while this works initially, these alerts start stacking as the user plays more and more without refreshing the page, producing bizarre, inaccurate claims that seems to follow little to no pattern.  What's the deal?

I'm not sure where things could be going wrong, so I'm going to post pretty much all the script.  Sorry:

```
    function beginGame(limit){

let time = 0;
const timeInterval = setInterval(add2time, 1000);

function add2time()
{
    time += 1;
    $("#timer").text(time);
    if(time == 60 && limit == 'oneMin')
    {
        cease_and_eval();
    }
    if(time == 120 && limit == 'twoMin')
    {
        cease_and_eval();
    }

}

let score = 0;
const hit = new Audio("hit.flac");
const miss = new Audio("miss.mp3");
$(".begin").prop("disabled", true);
$("#stop").prop("disabled", false);

function moveMole(){    
let moleSpot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;


//needs to be 10, otherwise mole gets stuck in last hole
//this basically wipes the slate clean before placing a mole, so there won't be more than one on the screen a a time.
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("im" + i).setAttribute("src", "hole.png");
  
}

//this places the mole in a new spot
document.getElementById("im" + moleSpot).setAttribute("src", "mole.png");

}

const moleMovingInterval = setInterval(moveMole, 1000);


//I'm putting the stoping function inside the beginGame function
function cease_and_eval(){

alert("You scored " + score + " points in " + time + " seconds, or " + (score/time).toFixed(4) + " points per second.")
    //this is the ceasing
    console.log("this function is firing")
clearInterval(moleMovingInterval);
clearInterval(timeInterval)
score = 0;
time = 0;
$("img").attr("src", "hole.png");
$("#score").text(score);
$("#timer").text(time);
$("#stop").prop("disabled", true)
$(".begin").prop("disabled", false)
}

//having the event listener for the stop function spawned here
$("#stop").click(function(){
cease_and_eval()
});

$("img").click(function()
{
    
    
    if($(this).attr("src") == "mole.png")
    {
        hit.pause();
        hit.currentTime = 0;
        hit.volume = 0.3;
        hit.play();
        
    $(this).attr("src", "whacked.png");
    score++;
    $("#score").text(score);    
    }
    else
    {
        miss.pause();
        miss.currentTime = 0;
        miss.play()
    }
})

}
```

Comment: Did you put the clearIntervals in front of the "alert"? I could imagine that the intervals stacking up a bit until the user closes the alert and are still being fired a couple of times